# Different action with the same entity in controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity "Page" which possesses a slug.
I get this slug in my controller to render the proper content.
I would like to have a different behavior for specific pages.
The only solution I found is to switch depending on the slug.
The problem is that if the slug changes (SEO) I also need to change it in the controller.

```
class Page extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"frontname"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;

//...
```

Page Controller:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{

public function showAction(Request $request)
{
    $slug = $request->get('slug_page');

    $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Autre')->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));
    if (!$page) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Page introuvable.');
    }
    switch($slug){
         case  'notre-equipe': 
                 return $this->render('@App/Frontend/equipe/list.html.twig');
   // etc....
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle::Frontend/page/index.html.twig', array(
        'page' => $page,
    ));
}

}
```

Is there any cleaner solution to do that ?
I'm using symfony 2.7.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could create routes based on the slug value but then you would need to update the routing file when slugs change.  Same sort of problem.  You need to map the slug value somewhere and if the value changes then the mapping will need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to make the slug part of your URL:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{slug}", name="page_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($slug)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Autre')->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Autre entity.');
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
    );
}
```